# How to initialize List< List<Int> > in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

As per leetcode question [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/) I am required to return `List<List<Int>>` type for Kotlin submission.
I tried using `listOf()` but unable to create.
My another guess was to use LinkedList of type List:

```
var result: List<List<Int>> = LinkedList<List<Int>>()
```

The intelliJ idea gives no warnings for the above declaration but `add()` is not available on result variable. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

How should I initialize empty `List<List<Int>>` type in kotlin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`add` is not available for `List`. It's available for `MutableList`. `LinkedList` is a `MutableList`, but you are upcasting it to a plain `List` by assigning it to a variable of type `List`.

If you need to work with a MutableList or LinkedList inside this function, you can do so by not declaring the type of the `result` variable so it will implicitly be a MutableList or LinkedList. When you return it from the function, it will be implicitly upcast at that time, when you no longer need the mutable features.

```
fun threeSum(nums: IntArray): List<List<Int>> {
    val output = mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()

    // logic

    return output
}
```

or

```
fun threeSum(nums: IntArray): List<List<Int>> {
    val output = LinkedList<LinkedList<Int>>()

    // logic

    return output
}
```

LinkedList is a specific type of MutableList that compared to the default MutableList (ArrayList) is heavier and slower at accessing specific elements in the middle, but faster at accessing elements at the start/end and faster at inserting or removing elements. You will most commonly just want to use `mutableListOf` to instantiate mutable lists.

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
var result: List<List<Int>> = listOf(listOf())
```

or

```
var result = listOf(listOf<Int>())
```

Comment: This is a bit wrong, becuase `listOf(listOf())` will add an empty list to `result`, resulting in `[[]]` if we print the list value (An empty list inside an empty list, because `listOf()` creates an empty list). I would suggest using `val result= listOf<List<Int>>()` as this will create an empty list and having `List<Int>` as type and it will be able to accept `IntArray`'s (Or in OP's case we would use `val result= mutableListOf<MutableList<Int>>()` as we would like to modify the list by adding to it)